# How to automatically open a console when debugging a MacOS app with .NET in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

When creating a MacOS app with .NET using Visual Studio for Mac, I'm facing difficulty in obtaining the Console.WriteLine output during debugging. Currently, I launch the .app bundle through the terminal, which is quite cumbersome.

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio for Mac to automatically open a console when I start debugging, so I can easily view the Console.WriteLine output without the need for additional steps? Many answers suggest navigating to "View -> Pads -> Application Output" but this option seems to be missing in Visual Studio for Mac